# css,How to set a position of scroll as per active row in table

Tags: javascript, html, css

I m doing one project in that, 
The hight of div is 400px; fixed height and overflow:auto;
There is a table having 100 rows Displaying Data Dynamically,
Now when i refresh page my highlighted rows goes down and scroll positio is up;
I want that, when page is refresh the highlighted Row should be focused and position of scroll not in top as per content,

Thanks In advance

---

Some HTML:

```
 <div style="overflow:auto; width:400px; height:300px;" >
```

Comment: Code: <div style="overflow:auto; width:400px; height:300px;" >

Comment: And please specify whether you are using stuff like PHP, ASP, jQuery? And please clarify `displaying data dynamically`, what techniques are used to populate the table?

Comment: that simple HTML code is not enough, we'd need Javascript and PHP code for the dynamic reload as well.

Answer (score 0):

When the page is refreshed, all date/values/selections that you loaded/changed/set dynamically using Javascript on the *client side* is typically lost.

Unless you stored the selections ***server side*** as well.

For example with a `POST` to a certain PHP script that stores the selected value in the PHP global `$_SESSION` variable. And the page refresh then analyzes the `$_SESSION` variable to find out what default data/selections to set.

See also this related question:
[how to retain the div contents after page refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694191/how-to-retain-the-div-contents-after-page-refresh)