# How to retain JQuery appended values after page refresh?

Tags: jquery

How to retain JQuery appended values after page refresh? However every time I refresh the page, whatever that has been .append() disappears.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

jQuery(window).load(function() { 
var amt1 = jQuery("form.cart_group").find(".component.paged:eq(0)").find("span.woocommerce-Price-amount.amount").text();

var single_amt = amt1.split("Rs.");
var amount1 = single_amt[1];
 jQuery(".widget_shopping_cart_content li.mini_cart_item").append("<div>Domain: Rs."+amount1+"</div><br/>"); 
});
});
```

Comment: You cant retain anything that has been added after page load, for next page refresh. It has to be stored somewhere else. Cookies or Localstorage might be a good idea

Comment: refer [Dynamic content retain after page refresh](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24495001/retain-dynamically-generated-input-fields-via-jquery-after-refresh)

Also refer [how to retain the div contents after page refresh](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694191/how-to-retain-the-div-contents-after-page-refresh)

Comment: can you write me a code?

Comment: you can use hidden input fields to hold values then append them from the input fields. Input fields values don't clear out even after page refresh

Answer (score 0):

There are few solutions to your problem.(i would go with cookie or local storage)

- database-require server side support
- a cookie(it's very easy to use this one)
- a generated page (can be cached)
- via an ajax query to get the page "changes"

easiest way to save content locally is with HTML5 **LocalStorage**.

You could save data to an object:

```
var prefs = {
    div1: {
        text: 'something',
        class: 'test',
        parent: '#left'
    },
    div2: {...},
    ...
}
```

and then save this object to **localStorage**:

```
localStorage.savedPrefs = JSON.stringify(prefs);
```

When the page loads, check this object and take action accordingly:

```
if ('savedPrefs' in localStorage) {
    prefs = JSON.parse(localStorage.savedPrefs);
    // change page based on prefs
    // e.g. alert('div1 text: ' + prefs.div1.text);
}
```

Comment: can you modify my code cause i dont understand properly.

Answer (score 0):

use localStorage to store and retrieve data on page refresh

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery(window).load(function() { 
    var amountStored;
    var amt1 = jQuery("form.cart_group").find(".component.paged:eq(0)").find("span.woocommerce-Price-amount.amount").text();
    var single_amt = amt1.split("Rs.");

    var amount1 = single_amt[1];
    if(!localStorage.getItem("amount")){
        localStorage.setItem("amount",amount1)
    }
    else{
        amountStored = 0;
    }
    var amountStored = localStorage.getItem("amount")
    jQuery(".widget_shopping_cart_content li.mini_cart_item").append("<div>Domain: Rs."+amountStored+"</div><br/>"); 
});
```

});

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: yes i have tried this one but if I refesh more than two time append values gets disappear and showing the value of zero.

Comment: Even before I got the value if page has been refeshed append values gets disappears. but where as now append values itself coming zero.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the item to localstorage this way

```
var value = "YOUR APPEND STRING";
localStorage.setItem("YourData" , value);
```

Later when you reload the page in future, get it with following

```
var data=localStorage.getItem("GetData");
```